# Will an unreferenced object used in an anonymous class instance not expire?

Tags: java, multithreading

Assume this code:

```
public class Foo {

    public static Thread thread;
    public String thing = "Thing!!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo().makeThread();
        // <- Foo object may get garbage collected here.
        thread.start();
    }

    private void makeThread() {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // !! What if the instance of Foo is long gone?
                System.out.println(thing);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here, a temporary object `new Foo()` creates a statically held `Thread thread` which utilizes an instance-tied `String thing` in an anonymous implementation of `Runnable`. Does the `String thing` get garbage collected after expiration of `new Foo()`, or will it persist for its use within `run()`? Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string will not be garbage-collected until `thread` is set to `null` or to some other `Thread`, because there is a chain of references leading to the object from a static variable.

The chain of references looks like this:

`static thread` implicitly references the instance of `Foo` from which it has been created through an instance of anonymous class derived from `Runnable`. In turn, the instance of `Foo` holds a reference to `thing`, making sure that the object does not get garbage collected.

> What if the instance of Foo is long gone?

`Foo` is not going anywhere, because it is kept live by the implicit reference from the `Thread` object.

**Note:** This answer intentionally ignores the effect of interning `String` objects created from string literals.

Comment: Just focusing on the chain of references and nothing else:  The Thread instance is kept alive by both the static reference and ,by its own stack; The anonymous Runnable instance is kept alive by the Thread; The Foo instance is kept alive by the _implicit_ reference from the anonymous Runnable; and finally the String instance is kept alive by the Foo.

Comment: The thread doesn't refer to the `Foo`. The thread refers to the `Runnable` which in turn refers to the `Foo`.

Answer (score 10):

The anonymous inner class will have a reference to the `Foo`, as that's how it is about to access `thing`. It's as if you had:

```
public class FooRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Foo foo;

    public FooRunnable(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(foo.thing);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
private void makeThread() {
    thread = new Thread(new FooRunnable(this));
}
```

So basically, while the new thread keeps an instance of the `Runnable` implementation alive, that in turn prevents the instance of `Foo` from being garbage collected.